# Logging terminal while running an install script of sorts

Tags: shell, logging

I have written an install script in shell that does some configuration of various things such as xserver, network, etc and then installs a few RPM's which is no problem. But I want to be able to log everything that goes to the terminal screen as well. Is this possible to do from within the script so if the end user runs ./Install.sh it will do everything (including the logging).

I have tried using "script" but doesn't work from within the Install.sh script itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
script logfilename install.sh
```

when the install.sh finished the run, the `script` end too - so, you get everything logged into `logfilename`.

Probably you can make it two-stage, so, you should rename your current `install.sh` into `install-stage2.sh` and your install.sh will contain:

```
script ./install.log ./install-stage2.sh
```

**UPDATE** from my `man script`

```
NAME
     script -- make typescript of terminal session

SYNOPSIS
     script [-akq] [-t time] [file [command ...]]

DESCRIPTION
     The script utility makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is useful for students who need
     a hardcopy record of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
     later with lpr(1).

     If the argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file.  If no file name is given, the typescript is
     saved in the file typescript.

     If the argument command is given, script will run the specified command with an optional argument vector instead
     of an interactive shell.
```

Comment: Tried script log.log Install.sh with no luck, it doesn't seem to start the script at all.