# How to capture escape sequences sent by terminal?

Tags: linux, ansi-escape

How would one capture the escape sequences as they are sent by a terminal application (say Konsole for example) ? For example, if you hit <kbd>PgDown</kbd>, what is sent to the virtual console ?

I would like to record the byte stream sent to the virtual console (like when I hit "Ctrl+C" what escape sequence it produced) to a file I can then read with hexdump.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging terminal while running an install script of sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350046/logging-terminal-while-running-an-install-script-of-sorts)

Comment: no, theis question provide information about what a script write etc. to log its execution. Here, I want to get the byte stream sent to the virtual console.

Comment: You just read your stdin normally. Escape sequences are a part of the stream. BTW Ctrl-C is not an escape sequence, it's a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small python script to do the trick :

```
#!/bin/env python

import curses
from pprint import pprint

buf = ''

def main(stdscr):
  global buf
  curses.noecho()
  curses.raw()
  curses.cbreak()
  stdscr.keypad(False)

  stop = stdscr.getkey()
  c = stdscr.getkey()
  buf = ''
  while c != stop:
    buf += c
    c = stdscr.getkey()

def run():
  curses.wrapper(main)
  pprint(buf)
  tmp = buf.encode('latin1')
  pprint([hex(x) for x in tmp])
  pprint([bin(x) for x in tmp])

run()
```

...It clear the screen, then type a key (e.g. <kbd>a</kbd>), then, type any thing, and type the same key as the first one to stop. Then, it will display all the bytes received (example : <kbd>a</kbd> [start recording]
 <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> [stop recording] <kbd>a</kbd> produces the bytes : `['0x1b', '0x62']` with my terminal